# PhoneGap Plugin (BluetoothSerial) doesn't work

Tags: android, cordova, plugins, ant

I'd like to create a PhoneGap App and open a connection to another device through Bluetooth (https://github.com/don/BluetoothSerial). I started with the sample projects but nothing seems to happen with my settings, no events are triggered / console shows nothing.

I'm new to Phonegap and after struggling for days with installing NodeJs, Cordova (4.0.0), Phonegap (3.6.0-0.21.19), Ant, getting new Java JDK (1.7.0_71), updating Android (23, target here is Android API19) I can build and run Android apps. I followed http://www.pycode.com/android/creating-a-phonegap-cordova-3.0-app-in-eclipse.html as installation guide.

Nevertheless I couldn't build the jar file for Cordova (Target "jar" is not found), paths are set correctly. I searched online but the existing posts didn't help. Actually I found out that it's better to just use the CordovaApp-CordovaLib as a library, so I used this instead. Anyway it seems like I can't use any plugins at the moment (added  in config.xml and gave Bluetooth permission in AndroidManifest.xml). I'm not even sure if this is the problem here.

Seems like many people are struggling with Phonegap and I hope somebody experienced the same issues and can help.. Thanks in advance!

**Update**

Figured out that the onDeviceReady method wasn't called at all. Checked for cordova.js (don't just use any!) and copied it into my C:\ProjectPath\platforms\android\assets\www folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quite embarrassing, maybe that's why nobody's answered. I used the PhoneGap Developer App - of course this couldn't work. Use cordova build to build apk and test it on device..